# IBM Connections, receiving "400 Bad Request" error while trying to unfollow a user

Tags: java, rest, ibm-connections

I am trying to use the IBM connections API and make a user stop following the profile of another user with following API.

I am getting a "400 Bad Request" error.

```
public class StopProfileFollowing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SocketFactory factory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            Socket socket = factory.createSocket("greenhouse.lotus.com", 443);
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
                    socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF8");
            out.write("POST /profiles/follow/atom/resources?source=profiles HTTP/1.1\r\n");
            out.write("HOST: servername\r\n");
            String encoding = new String(
                    Base64.encodeBase64("username:password".getBytes()));
            out.write("Authorization: Basic " + encoding + "\r\n");
            String data = "<entry xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"  xmlns:app=\"http://www.w3.org/2007/app\"  xmlns:snx=\"http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn\">\n"
                    + " <category term=\"resource-follow\" scheme=\"http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type\" >   </category>\n"
                    + " <category term=\"profiles\" scheme=\"http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/source\"></category>\n"
                    + " <category term=\"profiles\" scheme=\"http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/resource-type\"></category>\n"
                    + " <category term=\"4f520868-ac2a-40bd-98da-a24e5227f529\" scheme=\"http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/resource-id\"></category>\n"
                    + "</entry>";
            out.write("Content-Length: " + data.length() + "\r\n");
            out.write("Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8 \r\n");
            out.write("\r\n");
            out.write(data);
            out.flush();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The body data here doesn't appear to contain any Unicode chars above 007F, but if it did the value for content-length would be wrong (too low) for the actual data bytes in UTF8 because `String.length()` is in decoded *characters* (and actually Java's `char` is UTF16 where that matters i.e. outside BMP).

Comment: @dave is correct - change to data.getBytes() and you should get a different result

Comment: @PaulBastide String.getBytes(/*nothing*/) uses the JVM default encoding which might or might not be UTF8; use getBytes("UTF8") (or canonically "UTF-8") to be reliable. The data *posted* doesn't give a different result, because it consists entirely of characters that are 1-byte in UTF8, but OP might be using other data that does.